# Moq Mocking and tracking Session values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mocking, moq

I'm having problems returning a Session value set from mocking using Moq. Using the following

```
public class TestHelpers
{
 public long sessionValue = -1;
 public HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext()
 {

  var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
  var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
  httpContext.Setup(x => x.Session).Returns(session.Object);
  httpContext.SetupGet(x => x.Session["id"]).Returns(sessionValue);
  httpContext.SetupSet(x => x.Session["id"] = It.IsAny<long>())
        .Callback((string name, object val) =>
        {
           sessionValue = (long)val;
        });
  }
}
```

When I try to obtain the value outside using

```
var th = new TestHelpers();
HttpContextBase httpContext = th.FakeHttpContext();
```

*do some stuff that sets Session["id"]*

```
var sessionid = httpContext.Session["id"];
```

sessionid turns out to be -1. But I can obtain the set session value using

```
th.sessionValue
```

What's wrong? Can't I simply return the set value via Moq?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I need to stop answering my own questions. It turns out that I needed to mock Session["id"] again like so ...

```
httpContext.SetupSet(x => x.Session["id"] = It.IsAny<long>())
        .Callback((string name, object val) =>
        {
           sessionValue = (long)val;
           httpContext.SetupGet(x => x.Session["id"]).Returns(sessionValue);
        });
```

Comment: This did not work for me: @Konamimam appears to be correct that the .Callback does not get fired. The correct approach seems to be here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2921695/213609

Answer (score 2):

Moq's `Setup` methods do not work with indexed properties that have string indexes. See here: [How to MOQ an Indexed property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340827/how-to-moq-an-indexed-property)

Comment: if it doesn't work then shouldn't Session["id"] return null and not -1?

Comment: Also, the answers to the question you linked to seem to indicate it works?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're returning the value in the getter which was passed by value.  So everytime you invoke the getter, you get the same value returned.

Change the Returns() to use a delegate so it is evaluated every time.  That way you will get the correct value every time :)

Much easier on the eye than a SetupGet embedded inside a SetupSet.

```
httpContext.SetupSet(x => x.Session["id"] = It.IsAny<long>())
        .Callback((string name, object val) => sessionValue = (long)val);
httpContext.SetupGet(x => x.Session["id"]).Returns(() => sessionValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just spent long time trying to figure out the easiest way to do it with moq, below is a copy past of my code that actually worked for me :

```
var _adminctrl = new Moq.Mock<AdminController>(); //AdminController is my MVC controller

var mock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
mock.Object.Controller = _adminctrl.Object;
mock.Setup(p => p.HttpContext.Session["UserInfoKey"]).Returns(new ViewModel());
 //here is the catch, attaching the ControllerContext to your controller
_adminctrl.Object.ControllerContext = mock.Object;
```

hope this helps!