# Using Moq to set indexers in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, indexer

I'm having trouble figuring out how to set [indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) in C# with Moq. The Moq documentation is weak, and I've done a lot of searching... what I'd like to do is similar in the solution to [How to Moq Setting an Indexed property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372938/how-to-moq-setting-an-indexed-property):

```
var someClass = new Mock<ISomeClass>();
someClass.SetupSet(o => o.SomeIndexedProperty[3] = 25);
```

I want to modify the above to work for any index and any value so I can just do something like this:

```
someClass.Object.SomeIndexedProperty[1] = 5;
```

Currently I have the following, which works great for the indexed property getter, but if I ever set the value Moq ignores it:

```
var someValues = new int[] { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
var someClass = new Mock<ISomeClass>();
someClass.Setup(o => o.SomeIndexedProperty[It.IsAny<int>()])
    .Returns<int>(index => someValues[index]);

// Moq doesn't set the value below, so the Assert fails!
someClass.Object.SomeIndexedProperty[3] = 25;
Assert.AreEqual(25, someClass.Object.SomeIndexedProperty[3]);
```

Comment: What is the index variable? Where is it coming from?

Comment: I'm new to Moq so maybe I'm doing something wrong... but I thought the index parameter in the Returns lambda was being provided by the It.IsAny<int>() expression in the Setup lambda.

Comment: I am not an expert either (I am using RhinoMocks). Does someClass.Object.SomeIndexedProperty[3] return 40?

Comment: Yes, that is the observed behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. It requires a shift in my thinking... I had been looking to use NUnit's `Assert` to verify that the indexer setter in my `someClass` mock was being called with the correct value.

It seems that with Moq the supported way to do this is to use the `VerifySet` function. A contrived example:

```
someClass.Object.SomeIndexedProperty[3] = 25;
someClass.VerifySet(mock => mock.SomeIndexedProperty[3] = 25);
```

The unit test passes since `SomeIndexedProperty[3]` is set to 25, but would fail otherwise.

Comment: I have the same issue, only my indexed property is readonly, that is it only has a `get` accessor. Any ideas on how I can mock this?

Answer (score 6):

Using Moq 3.1.416.3

Setup won't work for indexers (because it takes an expression which means assignment statements are ruled out)

so you need to use SetupSet like

```
_settingsStore.SetupSet(store => store["MruNotes"] = It.IsAny<string>())
                .Callback<string,string>( (key, value) => persistedValue = value);
```

A small caveat:
this expression only matches if the key is "MruNotes". I was not able to use a matcher like It.IsAny for the key.

Answer (score 3):

In your test your only set expectations for the getter of the indexer - and this will always return the corresponding value from your array. The indexer doesn't behave like a real thing. You can try a few things to have it fixed:

1. You can check if you can stub this indexer. I am personally using RhinoMocks, so I have no idea if this is implemented

   ```
   someClass.SetupProperty(f => f.SomeIndexedProperty);
   ```
2. You can try to mock the setter as well and make it to change the underlying array. My first guess would be to try something along these lines (no guarantee it will work):

   ```
   someClass.Setup(o => o.SomeIndexedProperty[It.IsAny<int>()] = It.IsAny<int>())
   .Callback((index, value) => someValues[index] = value);
   ```
3. Or if the ISomeClass interface is small enough, you could just created a stub implementation yourself (that would have the indexer implemented as a dictionary, array etc.)

Comment: #1 did not work in my experiments. I was attempting to do something like #2, but I didn't try a callback. Also thanks for pointing out #3--sometimes you end up trying to hammer in a screw instead of just finding a screwdriver.