# cannot implement setters (Moq)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, getter-setter

I have next interface

```
    public interface IMyInterface
{
    string this[string key] { get; set; }
}
```

and i want implement get/set in my test

```
var _Nvp = //...
var mockMyInterface = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
        mockMyInterface
            .Setup(e => e[It.IsAny<string>()])
            .Returns((string key) => _Nvp[key]);

        mockMyInterface
            .SetupSet(c => c[It.IsAny<string>()] = It.IsAny<string>())
            .Callback((string key, string value) => { _Nvp[key] = value; }));
```

But it does not work.. No errors, no messages..

```
        var oj = mockMyInterface.Object;
        oj["key"] = "value";
        var value = oj["key"];
```

Variable value is always null.

Comment: What is _Nvp? A dictionary? Have you debugged to see if your setter callback is being called (ie is _Nvp["key"] being set?

Comment: Have you tried `SetupGet` instead of `Setup`?

Comment: yes, dictionary.
getter - called but setter not called.

Comment: UrbanEsc , problem with setter. _Nvp is empty too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the following [SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4293273/1373170).

It seems there is a limitation on Moq's side resolving `c[It.IsAny<string>()]` on the SetupSet. It seems to work when specific keys are specified.

In your case you might want to go with a Stub with internal state implementing your interface rather than a mock.