# How to set up mock for indexer property?

Tags: c#, properties, installation, mocking, moq

I'm not expert with mocking, but I know mocks advantages. I face with a problem where I have an interface you can see it below. I want to Setup this interface get property in the right way.

```
public interface IInterface
{
    string this[string key] { get; }
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
Mock<IInterface> mockInterface = new Mock<IInterface();
mockInterface.SetupGet(mockInterface.Object).Returns("Test");
```

But I get the following error:

> Error    CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Mock.SetupGet(Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Can you give me some advice or solution for this problem?

Comment: Have a look at `Task.FromResult("Test")`

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340827/how-to-moq-an-indexed-property) should answer your question. That kind of property is called an [`Indexer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/).

Comment: @John I'm coming with a beer to you thanks! :beer: