# How to mock a HttpContext.GetServerVariable() in .NET Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, nunit-3.0

I'm trying to test below method with NUnit and Moq in .NET Core environment:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeviceType()
{
    string deviceIp = HttpContext.GetServerVariable("REMOTE_ADDR");
    var result = await DeviceService.GetTypeForAsync(deviceIp);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

The problem is mock a `HttpContext.GetServerVariable`. I've tried to mock context and insert it by `ControllerContext`:

```
var actionContext = new Mock<ActionContext>();
var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
httpContext.Setup(x => x.GetServerVariable(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("192.168.1.1");
actionContext.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(httpContext.Object);
//...
var deviceController = new DeviceController();
deviceController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(actionContext.Object);
```

But test not passed and throw an error:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.GetServerVariable(It.IsAny())
> Extension methods (here: HttpContextServerVariableExtensions.GetServerVariable) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

The question is: how to mock `HttpContext.GetServerVariable("REMOTE_ADDR")`?

Comment: If you look at the source code for the extension method, you will see that it gets the variables via the feature collection on the `Features` property. You'd need to provide a mock `IServerVariablesFeature` from there in your `HttpContext`: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/ee4e9a8293ef7d1f717596bd8fbaa57e20626633/src/Http/Http.Extensions/src/HttpContextServerVariableExtensions.cs#L19-L29

Answer (score 2):

As the error indicates, you can't mock an extension method, as that's a static method, not an overridable or implementable instance or interface method.

The [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpcontextservervariableextensions.getservervariable?view=aspnetcore-5.0) lives in [`HttpContextServerVariableExtensions`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Http/Http.Extensions/src/HttpContextServerVariableExtensions.cs), and merely gets the `IServerVariablesFeature` feature from the context and forwards the call to that implementation.

So, also mock the `IServerVariablesFeature` [and its `this[string]` indexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340827/how-to-moq-an-indexed-property), and let that mock's object be returned from your mocked `HttpContext.Features`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to great tips from @martin-costello and @codecaster I'm finally able to mock it:

```
var serverVarsFeature = new Mock<IServerVariablesFeature>();
serverVarsFeature.Setup(x => x["REMOTE_ADDR"]).Returns("192.168.1.1");           
var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContext>();
httpContext.Setup(x => x.Features.Set(serverVarsFeature.Object));
// ...
var deviceController = new DeviceController();
deviceController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext();
deviceController.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext(httpContext.Object.Features);
```